# How to obtain a correct -| Bond Graph arrow with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

When I tried to make paths drawn using `-|` or `|-` with a Bond Graph arrow (`f_out` or `e_out`) in a Tikzpicture I obtain this (the red circles show the wrong location of the end of the arrows):

[image]

I would prefer this:

[image]

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bondgraphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (node1) [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em] {node1};%
\path (node1.east)+(3,0) node (node2) [draw, text width=3em, minimum height=3em] {node2};%
\draw [bond, e_out] ( $ (node1.north east)!0.15!(node1.east) $ ) -| node [above, pos=0.2] {label1} (node2.north);%
\draw [bond, f_out]  (node2.south)  |- node [below, pos=0.8] {label2}  ( $ (node1.south east)!0.15!(node1.east) $ );%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Could anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `bondgraph` does not properly handle paths drawn using `-|` or `|-`. The simplest solution I can offer

1. Use the `no bond` style to get the same thickness on the portions where you don't want the `bond`.
2. Break the path into two components and use `no_bond` on the first and `bond` on the second:

   ```
   \draw [no bond, f_out] (node2.south) -- (X);
   \draw [bond] (X) -- (Y);
   ```

   where `(X)` and `(Y)` are the intermediate points.

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bondgraphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{no bond/.style={thick}}% <-- to get similar appearange

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node (node1) [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em] {node1};%
    \path (node1.east)+(3,0) node (node2) [draw, text width=3em, minimum height=3em] {node2};%
    
    \draw [no bond, e_out] ( $ (node1.north east)!0.15!(node1.east) $ ) -| node [above, pos=0.2] {label1} (node2.north);% <-- changed style
    %\draw [bond, f_out]  (node2.south)  |- node [below, pos=0.8] {label2}  ( $ (node1.south east)!0.15!(node1.east) $ );%
    \coordinate (Y) at ($(node1.south east)!0.15!(node1.east)$);
    \coordinate (X) at ($(node2.south)!(Y)!(node2.south)$);
    \draw [no bond, f_out] (node2.south) -- (X);
    \draw [bond] (X) -- (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer, It meets my need. However, do you know by chance how can I "shift" the end of the top arrow regarding relative coordinate - with something like `($(node2.north west)!0.15!(node2.north)$)` (see the first edit of my question for more details). Thanks again !

Comment: You have several options: 1. You could apply a `xshift=` to move the point `(node2.north)`.  For example, you could use `([xshift=-0.25cm]node2.north)`. 2. You could specify the "angle" position, something like `(node2.120)`.  In general, it is a good idea to keep questions to be specfic to _one_ particular issue. That way, when others have a similar issue in the future, they are more likely to be able to find it. In this case, somone looking to move a node to the left will probably ignore a question about `bond` graphs.

Comment: Ok I have posted another answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633831/262081). Thanks a lot for your comment.